# Hyperledger Fabric Databases (Relational/NoSQL)

Tags: database, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

I am a just starting out on trying Hyperledger Fabric and I am slightly confused on how it's ledger/blockchain part really works.

I've read that it has a World State Ledger and a Blockchain part, where the world state ledger uses LevelDB or CouchDB which I think is a NoSQL database? Is it possible to use a Relational Database for the State Ledger? If not, why must we use a NoSQL database? Also, does the blockchain part require a database, or else where and how do we look at its data, where is it stored? My questions might be abit conflicting as I am kinda confused right now about the Architecture of Hyperledger Fabric.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a beginner in hyperledger fabric than keep reading this [document](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/)

For your levelDB and CouchDB queries refer [this](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/cl-top-technical-advantages-of-hyperledger-fabric-for-blockchain-networks/)

And if you want to know how actually fabric network works in short than refer [this](https://medium.com/coinmonks/how-does-hyperledger-fabric-works-cdb68e6066f5)

And I recommend that first, you try to understand blockchain technology and how it is differently implemented by some frameworks like ethereum, hyperledger, corda, bigchainDB, EOS, etc...